# Specific reference to ADD to gain access to the IsEditable property of a combo box control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've got the basic combo box working fine, but I want to prevent the user from simply entering their own entry in the edit portion of the control, bypassing the dropdown list I have populated for them.  I am prepared to compare (and reject) entries to my list if necessary.

It seems that the correct combination of the `IsEditable` property and the `IsReadOnly` property will do the trick, but I am not able to access either of those parameters.  My research suggests that I need to do some binding or maybe need to add a reference or add a newer dll or something similar.  There was a mention of property `dependecy` that seemed promising, but not sure how to confirm or deny or fix.

I'm sure that I could do one of those things, but I've go no idea how to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question, you want the user to not be able to type into the comboBox and just be able to select one of the options you put?

Like this?

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True">
      <TextBlock><Run Text="option 1"/></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock><Run Text="option "/></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock><Run Text="option 3"/></TextBlock>
  </ComboBox>
```

Please clarify if that is not what you want, and I will change my answer

Comment: The Remarks section of [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a two by two grid that shows how the 'IsEditable' property interacts with the 'IsReadOnly' property of a combobox.  I want the second bullet point to be "Cannot enter a string that does not correspond to an item in the ComboBox.".  So there are three out of four combinations of the two properties that will give me the behaviour that I want.

Comment: A better answer:  Yes, that is the behaviour that I want.  To clarify I'm working with VB and Windows Forms.  In design mode the IDE does not present either of 'IsEditable' or 'IsReadOnly' as properties that I can set.  This is the case if I try to set the properties in code and also if I just try to set the properties in the Properties Window.

Comment: @OldDogNewTricks... no idea about winforms, I changed your tag so it will be posted to the correct area, im sure you will find your answer there

Comment: I have not been able to answer my question.    But I have solved my problem.  I've changed the DropDownStyle to DropDownList (2) from DropDown (1), and now I get the behaviour that I want. I still hope to figure out why my other solution failed someday.

Comment: Glad to hear it:)